# Error: failed to find target with hash string 'android-21'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-appcompat

I want to change my compileSdkVersion from 23 to 21.So I have made following changes in the build.gradle but I am getting following error.How can I resolve this?

**failed to find target with hash string 'android-21'**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.shalabh.fly"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1-beta1.jar')
    }
```

Comment: and you did download it, didn't you ?

Comment: Yeah I have downloaded sdk21

Comment: does Android Studio give some hint about what's  missing ?

Comment: Failed to sync gradle project and just the error

Comment: Can you check whether the folder named android-21 is listed under sdk/platforms/ path of your android installation.

Comment: no Alok there is not android-21 folder.I think thats the problem.What to do?

Comment: Try re-installing the android-21 platform tools , if you haven't already.

Answer (score 3):

You are using

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

**So you have to compile with API 23.**
Change your `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` file

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is for Android studio
1. Go to **app -> build.gradle -> change "compileSdkVersion 'installed sdk version'"**

2. Go to **Tools -> Android -> sync project with gradle files**

That's it, problem solved:-)

Comment: it worked! (just for anybody who is reading app is a folder in Project)

Answer (score 2):

> Note: I think this might be a bug in Android Studio.

---

1. Go to Project Structure
2. Select App Module
3. Under the first tab "Properties" change the Compile SDK Version to API XX from Google API xx (e.g. API 23 instead of Google API 23)
4. Press OK
5. Wait for the completion of on going process, in my case I did not get an error at this point.
6. Now revert Compiled Sdk Version back to Google API xx.

If this not work, then:

7. With Google API (Google API xx instead of API xx), lower the build tool version (e.g. Google API 23 and build tool version 23.0.1)
8. Press Ok and wait for completion of on going process
9. Revert back your build tool version to what it was before you changed
10. Press Ok and Wait for the completion of process.
11. Done!

Answer (score 1):

Go to you Android SDK dir and install it properly:

```
tools/android update sdk
```

or

```
tools/android update sdk --no-ui
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]This error I also getting again and again when I import other's project.
  So I resolve to change some in Gradle file according to my system.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

Which I have already installed  in my system.

Comment: This fellow have some and he try to import the android project and he don't that build enviorment.

Answer (score 0):

Just check android home environment variable, it should be :
   path/../path/sdk
and not : 
   path/.../path/sdk/tools
example:
   android home path is : /home/username/android/sdk
   you should put the following lines to .bashrc file in user home directory:

```
 ANDROID_HOME='/home/username/android/sdk'
 PATH="$HOME:$HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
 export ANDROID_HOME
 export PATH
```