# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-L'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I tried all the solutions here & there on stackoverflow but still getting this error even though i updated the :-

1. compileSdkVersion 27
2. buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
3. targetSdkVersion 27

[image: Screenshot of error]

Already tried these threads solutions but nothing seems to work:-

[Error: failed to find target with hash string 'android-21'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330964/error-failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-21)

[Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457524/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-25)

Comment: Just click on `install missing plateforms and sync project`.

Comment: "The following packages are not available: - - Package id platforms;android-L.

Comment: android-L is the preview version of android-21. For now, fix your archaic modules to have `compileSdkVersion 21`. (By that I mean both [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/) and [Google Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) are now delivered via *maven* in *modular* packages. But your project looks like it holds local copies of an old version of these libraries.) The error message, un-conveniently cut-off, tells you which of your modules is misconfigured.

Comment: I changed it but can't solve the problem